# COM Interop error 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED) when using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer

I am using WinForm application to open a new IE browser with height and width and I got below exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010108): The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))

And the code it seems to be referencing:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

dynamic ie = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application");

string URL = "https://www.google.com/";
ie.ToolBar = 0;
ie.StatusBar = false;
ie.MenuBar = false;
ie.Width = 800;
ie.Height = 550;
ie.Visible = true;
ie.Resizable = false;
ie.AddressBar = false;
ie.Visible = true;
ie.Top = 230;
ie.Left = 300;
ie.Navigate(URL);
SetForegroundWindow(ie.Hwnd)
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.  Do favor WebBrowser.

Comment: Internet Explorer is on its way out.  Do as Hans suggests, and use the [WebBrowser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx).  Or find yourself a nice little 3rd party browser/control to integrate.